# MySql Insert Foreign key Constraint Fails

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Students and Courses. A Student can en-roll in multiple courses. Here is the EER diagram I have for the tables

[image]

I have records both in Student and Course table with Ids 1. When I enter into student_courses table those two Ids , i am getting back foreign_key constraint failed error.

```
FOREIGN KEY (`student_courses_sno`) REFERENCES `courses` (`sno`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE )
```

**Error Message**

> ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`pp_production`.`student_courses`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_student_courses_courses1` FOREIGN KEY (`courses_sno`) REFERENCES
>   `courses` (`sno`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE ) SQL Statement:
>   INSERT INTO `pp_production`.`student_courses` (`sno`, `courses_sno`,
>   `students_sno`) VALUES ('1', '227', '1')

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Instead of the image, would please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for each of these 3 tables, and the exact `INSERT INTO student_courses...` statement that is failing?

Comment: Could you also give the structure of student_offers and its EER?

Comment: Updated question with error message and insert statement.

Comment: What is `student_offers`?

Comment: sorry I meant student_courses